# Can we keep the installed application and created servers when running removeNode from WebSphere?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

Recently, we've got request to refederate current WAS 6.1 Node to new WAS 7.1 DmgrNode. Right now, that WAS 6.1 Node is running under V6.1 DmgrNode. 
From my understanding, when using removeNode against 6.1 Node, all the installed applications and servers inside would be removed consequently. Is that possible to get some way to keep these stuffs during the operation? Or any other solution to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is only possible by using the runtime migration tools that are included with the product runtime (WASPreUpgrade, WASPostUpgrade).  See the [migration planning presentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27008724&aid=6) in the [migration planning](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27008724) knowledge collection, specifically pages 29-31 and the various references in that document.